# How to overcome zero reachdist in density based outlier

Tags: data-mining, knn, outliers

I encounter a problem with my density based outlier detection program. Sometime, the sum of reachDist is zero. For example, my dataSet consists of { a=4,b=4,c=4,d=4,e=5,f=5,g=6 } and my K is 3. The sum of reachDist of a,b,c and d would be zero. May I know how to overcome this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

These points clearly are inliers, and should be givne a LOF of 1.